# Finding the limit $\lim_{z\to i}\frac{1}{z - i} - \frac{1}{z^2 + 1}$ with the properties of limits

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Here $i$ denotes the complex number $i$. The exercise is the exercise 5 of the section 2.2 from *Complex Analysis with Applications* by *Asmar*.

The limit itself is pretty simple. What bugs me is the model answer the author gives. Namely the steps given are i.) expand the rational to $\frac{z + i - 1}{(z + i)(z - i)}$, ii.) apply the limit $\lim_{z\to i }$ to numerator and denominator, iii.) conclude that the limit approaches $\infty$, as $\lim_{z\to c}f(z) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{z\to c}\frac{1}{f(z)} = \infty$.

Here's my problem with the model solution: 1.) The theorem for applying the limit $\lim_{z\to z_0}$ operator to numerator and denominator of a fraction $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ explicitly require that $g(z_0) \neq 0$, 2.) why $\lim_{z\to c}f(z) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{z\to c}\frac{1}{f(z)} = \infty$? Shouldn't there be a possibility for $\pm\infty$?

Comment: 2) Well yes, but there is no difference between $\pm\infty$ because what author trying to say it goes to infinity doesn't mattter if it is positive infinity or negative infinity. 1) consider $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ as $x\to 0$

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç For 1.), good point! While this may be pedantic, the exercise explicitly asked to argue about the limit with the properties of limits presented in the chapter, i.e. with the given theorems.

Comment: Note that the definition of complex function f that holds limit $/infty$ at a point, is that the absolute value goes to $/infty$ there.

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç There is no such thing as $\pm \infty$ in the complex plane. As pointed out by Ron $\lim \frac  1{f(z)} =\infty$ is supposed to mean  $\lim \frac  1{|f(z)|} =\infty$